# Getting ViewStub with @android:id/empty in Monodroid returns null

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In Monodroid I have a ListActivity class with the following axml segment:

```
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ViewStub
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout="@layout/empty" />
```

I'm trying to access the ViewStub with:

```
FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Empty);
```

However, it always returns null.  If I access the list with:

```
FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.List);
```

it works or if I name the ViewStub something other than @android:id/empty it works.  The ViewStub does work when my list is empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things I can think of that might be the issue.

The first issue could be that you have another UI page that defined the id of "empty" somewhere else.  MonoDroid puts all IDs from all pages into the same resource file, so you obviously can't have the same name twice.  Try putting empty2 to see if that works.

The next issue could be that you should have android:id=@id+/empty".  The + tells MonoDroid to generate an ID for the control in the Resource file.

Last, use something other than "empty".  Empty could be a reserved word by Android/MonoDroid, so I would avoid it.